# Windows 10 class not registered error

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 was working fine on my PC, but one morning when I booted my pc Windows 10 behaved strange.

Start, Edge and notification bar is not responding, and Edge and Store throws error:

```
class not registered
```

I have tried some tricks given on Windows forum also I have unchecked IE 11 in turn Windows features on/off, inside Control Panel, but nothing helped what suddenly happened to my PC...

Please help!

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_search/start-menu-doesnt-appear/a7c56613-277c-4993-bb74-08650dce7b21

Comment: Also I have unchecked internet explorer 11 in turn Windows features on and off inside control panel

Comment: You should update your question.  The fact you have IE11 uninstalled is likely connected to your problems.

Comment: I don't know how but I solved the problem , I created new Microsoft account but without administration permission and now it's working fine . If any one knows why it didn't work in administrator account ?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer (you will be able to accept it 2 days after posting the question)?  That will indicate that the problem has been solved, which people might not notice buried in a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, Windows 10... Updating to 1511 reduced that issue occurrence, but it still happens :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem can be solved easily by creating a new Microsoft account but without administrative permission and it would work fine .

Comment: Some kind of paliative solution, like creating userX / X ϵ N*, i.e. X = 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Certainly under the new account this error does not occur. But are you then saying that the "fix" to this problem is to abandon the original account? And all of it's settings?

Comment: How about if you need administrative permission?

Comment: Some other solutions would be as descibed here: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-10-start-button-not-working-solved/#m6